# Jest Test Scheduler method

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, testing, jestjs

I have a simply class which runs a scheduler.

Something like this:

```
export class ExportScheduler {
    constructor(cron: string, private product: Product) {
        cron.schedule(cron, () => this.export());
    }

    async export(): Promise<any> {
        const access = new Accessor(this.product);

        return access.calc();
    }
}
```

And I would like to write a test using Jest, which basically tests the scheduler.

```
beforeEach(() => {
    clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    cut = new ExportScheduler(
       '* * * * *',
        product
    );
   });

it('should schedule exports', async () => {
    expect(await cut.export).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    clock.tick(70000);
    expect(await cut.export).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}
```

But it tells me following:

> Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

How should I test this scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

You should utilize the `jest` global object here.

**Mock the CRON timer**

- Use [`jest.useFakeTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestusefaketimersimplementation-modern--legacy) to have Jest use fake versions of the standard timer functions. According to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9971) you'll need to pass it the string argument `"modern"` in order to mock timers like `Date` which are typically used by CRON schedulers.
- Use [`jest.advanceTimersByTime()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestadvancetimersbytimemstorun) to fast forward the timers in milliseconds.
- Use [`jest.clearAllTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestclearalltimers) to clear any timers that have been scheduled (but have not yet executed).

**Spy on the class method**

- Use [`jest.spyOn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to spy on the `.export()` method.

```
let cut

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern')

    cut = new ExportScheduler('* * * * *', product);
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
})

it('does not invoke .export(), before 60 seconds have passed', () => {
    const exportSpy = jest.spyOn(cut, 'export');

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(50000);

    expect(exportSpy).not.toBeCalled();
}

it('invokes .export() once, after 60 seconds have passed', () => {
    const exportSpy = jest.spyOn(cut, 'export');

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(60000);

    expect(exportSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
}
```

*Note that you do not actually need to use async since you are only asserting that the method was called. In this example you'd only want to make the test async if you planned on asserting the value of the `.export()`'s resolved promise.*